# Deploying MYSQL stuck in pending

Tags: openshift, openshift-3

Been trying to deploy an mysql in openshift 3 online.
And i get the following error. Any idea what's wrong with it?

[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that scheduling failed because on 175 machines wasn't enough CPU left available to fit the pod requests and on 5 machines (nodes) it can't be scheduled because those nodes don't have the particular set of labels the pod is specifying in [`spec.nodeSelector`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#nodeselector) of the pod definition.

So this simply means there weren't enough resources/hardware available at OpenShift Online. If you try later or upgrade your plan this should work again.